# Can you create cloudformation stacks in the CDK without using the cli?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Currently I have a cloudformation template in a yaml file that I use to form a stack containing the resources needed for my app. This works in most regions, but in some I need to modify the template depending on restrictions. The template yaml is constructed by stitching together different smaller yaml files to fit the purpose and restraints.

It has become a hassle to cut and modify these yaml files to achieve the desired resources in the stack, so I've started thinking about switching to the aws cdk instead.

The problem is that I do not want to enter a terminal and use the cdk cli everytime I want to create a stack. A stack is created for each instance of my app, which end users run and I cannot expect them to be interested in running cli commands to run my app.

**Can I create these stacks with the cdk without using cli commands?**

My app is written in java if that helps.

Comment: If you want your customers / users to have a UI you need to build a UI.

Comment: Do you currently expect them to manually combine yaml files?

Comment: "This works in most regions, but in some I need to modify the template depending on restrictions." you might be able to use cloudformation conditions, mappings, and intrinsic functions to do this all in the same template.

Comment: @luk2302 I have built a UI. The general thought is that when they run the installation phase of my app, they create their personal cloudformation stack by clicking a button.

Comment: after they click the button on your page, have it kick off a CodePipeline that synth's the CDK template and deploys it for you/them.